# Multiple edge creation - Gremlin REST server

Tags: javascript, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

I am using a simple Gremlin RESTful server and I am sending simple commands inside a POST request. For example, if I want to create edges (in my specific format), I have the following template:

`const nodeCommandFormat = "graph.addVertex('%s', '%s', 'evid', '%s');"`;

Sending a long string with chained commands like this works fine, all the edges are created. My question is: why it does not work with the edges creation? Until now, I tried with this two commands:

`const newEdgeCommandFormat = "g.V().has('evid', '%s').addE('next').to(g.V().has('evid', '%s')).property('count', 1);"`;

or

`x = g.V().has('evid', ...).next(); y = g.V().has('evid', ...).next(); x.addEdge('next', y, 'count', 1)`;

However, if I concatenate 100 commands like this, only the edge corresponding to the last command is created. Why is that? On the other hand, I also receive errors like this:

- **Using first type of edge creatio**n: [WARN] HttpGremlinEndpointHandler - Invalid request - responding with 500 Internal Server Error and The provided traverser does not map to a value: v[3091]->[TinkerGraphStep(vertex,[evid.eq(6ba0b28797dd79a2ee198d8ff280c4ff)])]
- **Using the second type of edge creation**: java.util.NoSuchElementException
  at org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.process.traversal.util.DefaultTraversal.next(DefaultTraversal.java:204)

How do I achive dynamic edge creation using Gremlin REST server?

P.S. All my nodes have "evid" property (event-id) which is the md5 value of an object. I use this as an identifier for my nodes.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`.iterate()` your traversals. This is highlighted in the [Getting Started tutorial](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/getting-started/) right at the end of the "The First 5 Minutes" section.